# How hide/remove footer in Sense/Net 6.5.4.9243

Tags: sensenet

Last week I have been working with Sense/Net 6.5.4.9243. Our main target is to use the workspace feature of sensenet ECM for our company. So I want to remove the footer and the header slider, but it shows "Error during rendering, please check the content view". (I made all the changes on the ui). 
[image: enter the image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer is defined and configured in the pagetemplate html (/Root/Global/pagetemplates/sn-layout-inter-index.html). If you want to delete it, go to the admin surface, open the html file and remove the lines 72-92.

[image]

To remove the header slider properly change to edit mode with the Portal Remote Control and choose delete from the portletmenu.

[image]